# Google Drive API Upload Format Invalid?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I've been using the following method to upload images to Google Drive:

```
    public string AddFile(string path, string contentType, string driveId)
    {
        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path,
            FileMode.Open))
        {
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
            {
                Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
                DriveId = driveId
            };
            request = _service.Files.Create(
                fileMetadata, stream, contentType);
            request.Fields = "id";
            request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
        }
        IUploadProgress requestResult = request.Upload();
        if (requestResult.Exception != null) throw requestResult.Exception;
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;
        return file == null ? "" : file.Id;
    }
```

It was working fine until today, using the API client library version 1.40.3.1694.  Now I get this sort of error in requestResult.Exception:

```
System.FormatException: The format of value 'bytes 0--1/660915' is invalid.
```

The file I'm uploading is just a small GIF test file that gets deleted right away in this case.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can I just check, you've not changed the library version, it just started happening without you changing anything? And does it happen for every request? I'd like to work out whether we've broken something in the client, or whether maybe there's a server problem.

Comment: I didn't change the library version.  It was happening for every request with PNG files at least. (see answer below for workaround)

Comment: When you say you're uploading a "small gif" - is it 645K, or smaller? If it's not 645K, that's very strange in terms of the error you're getting. (Sorry for all the questions - just trying to get all the info I'll need to reproduce it.)

Comment: It is exactly 645K.

Comment: I will send it to you in an email, if you like.

Comment: Nope, that's fine - I doubt that the content itself is important, but knowing that the range specified is the file size is good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand:

- Why the original code is broken
- Why using a `MemoryStream` fixes it
- How to fix it more simply

I don't yet understand:

- The *exact* error you're seeing (I'll dig into that separately; I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1449) for it)
- How your code has ever actually worked

The problem is that you're opening a `FileStream`, creating a request *but not executing it*, disposing of the `FileStream` and *then* executing the request. In your `MemoryStream` version, you don't dispose of the stream until the upload is complete.

Creating the initial request doesn't actually read the data from the stream - it just prepares things. You need to keep your stream open until `Upload` has completed. So all you need to do is make the `using` statement bigger:

```
public string AddFile(string path, string contentType, string driveId)
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
            DriveId = driveId
        };
        var request = _service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, contentType);
        request.Fields = "id";
        request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
        IUploadProgress requestResult = request.Upload();
        if (requestResult.Exception != null) throw requestResult.Exception;
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;
        return file == null ? "" : file.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: My second version has the memory stream using wrapped around the Upload call. That's probably why that one works.

Comment: @Riddari: Yes, exactly - sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the way to go about this correctly is to change the method to this:

```
public string AddFile(string path, string contentType, string driveId)
    {
        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path,
            FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                File fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
                {
                    Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
                    DriveId = driveId
                };
                request = _service.Files.Create(
                    fileMetadata, memoryStream, contentType);
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
                request.Upload();
            }
        }
        File file = request.ResponseBody;
        return file.Id;
    }
```

You need to copy the file stream into a memory stream and upload from that instead.  I'm still curious as to why that works, so if someone wants to get a checkmark, I would accept an answer that includes an explanation as to why this works but the one I put in my question doesn't.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this tomorrow. I don't know the Drive API as well as I know the Storage API, but if I can reproduce it, I should be able to figure out what's going on.